# Passing information between while True statments in python

Tags: python

'''
I am trying to figure out how to pass information between two while True statements. Basically when player1 asks for a card, I want to store that card in a list of remembered cards for player2. That way when it is player2's turn it can check its hand for that card and if it has it, it will ask for that card, otherwise; the random.choice function will pick the card. Next I want to make my player2 remember the cards it asks for that player1 doesn't have so I can prevent player2 from asking for that card for a certain amount of turns. I am basically trying to program my computer player to be smarter.
'''

```
remembered_cards = set()
for_player_2 = set()
while True:
    if len(player_1_hand) == 0 or len(player_2_hand) == 0 or len(deck) == 0:
        break
    # Player 1's turn
    while True:
        if len(player_1_hand) == 0:
            break
        print("Your cards ", player_1_pairs)
        desired_card = input("What card would you like?\n").upper()
        # Putting this here to try to help describe what I am trying to do
        for_player_2.add(desired_card)
        if check_guess(player_2_hand, player_1_hand, desired_card, player_1_pairs)== True:
            print("Well done")
        else:
            print("Go Fish")
            player_1_had.append(deal_top_card(deck))
            drawn_card = player_1_hand[-1]
            if check_d_card(player_1_hand, player_1_pairs, desired_card, drawn_card)== Tr:
                print("Congratulations, you drew the match to your pair!!!")
                continue
            elif check_d_card(player_1_hand, player_1_pairs, desired_card, drawn_card)==F:
                for i in range(len(player_1_hand)):
                    for j in range(i + 1, len(player_1_hand):
                        # If card ranks match
                        card1 = player_1_hand[i]
                        card2 = player_1_hand[j]
                        if card1[0] == card2[0]:
                            player_1_pairs.extend([card1, card2])
                            player_1_hand.remove(card1)
                            player_1_hand.remove(card2)
                            break
            break
    #Player 2's turn
    while True:
        if len(player_2_hand) == 0:
            break
        cardFound = False
        #This is where I need to fix
        while cardFound:
            for x in for_player_2:
                for j in player_2_hand:
                    if x[0] == j[0]:
                        cardFound == True
                        player_2_choice = j
                        print("Player 2 asked for ", player_2_choice)
                        break
        if not cardFound:
                player_2_choice = random.choice(player_2_hand)
                print("Player 2 asked for ", player_2_choice)
        if player_2_choice not in player_2_hand:
                continue

        if check_guess(player_1_hand, player_2_hand, player_2_choice, player_2_pairs)==Tr:
            print("Player 2 got a pat on the back for guessing correctly.")
        else:
            print("Player 2 had to go fishing!!!")
            drawn_card = player_2_hand[-1]
            if check_d_card(player_2_hand, player_2_pairs, player_2_choice, d_card)==True:
                print("Player 2 got a pat on the back for drawing their pair")
            elif check_d_card(player_2_hand, player_2_pairs, player_2_choice, d_card)==F:
                for i in range(len(player_2_hand)):
                    for j in range(i + 1, len(player_2_hand):
                        # If card ranks match
                        card1 = player_2_hand[i]
                        card2 = player_2_hand[j]
                        if card1[0] == card2[0]:
                            player_2_pairs.extend([card1, card2])
                            player_2_hand.remove(card1)
                            player_2_hand.remove(card2)
                            break
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize the `for_player_2` variable outside the loop then modify it  within the loop.

```
for_player_2 = [] # <<========================= initialize variable here
while True:
    if len(player_1_hand) == 0 or len(player_2_hand) == 0 or len(deck) == 0:
        break
    # Player 1's turn
    while True:
        if len(player_1_hand) == 0:
            break
        print("Your cards ", player_1_pairs)
        desired_card = input("What card would you like?\n").upper()
        # Putting this here to try to help describe what I am trying to do
        # for_player_2 = [] # <<==== remove this line
        for_player_2 += desired_card
        if check_guess(player_2_hand, player_1_hand, desired_card, player_1_pairs)== True:
            print("Well done")
        else:
            print("Go Fish")
            player_1_had.append(deal_top_card(deck))
            drawn_card = player_1_hand[-1]
            if check_d_card(player_1_hand, player_1_pairs, desired_card, drawn_card)== Tr:
                print("Congratulations, you drew the match to your pair!!!")
                continue
            elif check_d_card(player_1_hand, player_1_pairs, desired_card, drawn_card)==F:
                for i in range(len(player_1_hand)):
                    for j in range(i + 1, len(player_1_hand):
                        # If card ranks match
                        card1 = player_1_hand[i]
                        card2 = player_1_hand[j]
                        if card1[0] == card2[0]:
                            player_1_pairs.extend([card1, card2])
                            player_1_hand.remove(card1)
                            player_1_hand.remove(card2)
                            break
            break
    #Player 2's turn
    while True:
        if len(player_2_hand) == 0:
            break
        # This is the list that I am trying to limit the scope of
        print(for_player_2) # <<======  the variable is accessible here
        ##HERE## <<============
        card_found = False # a flag to be used later
        for card in for_player_2:
            for hand_card in player_2_hand:
                if hand_card[0] == card[0]:
                    card = hand_card
                    # ask for that card
                    # NB: I don't know what you mean by "ask for that card", so I will print it instead
                    print(card)
                    player_2_choice = card
                    card_found = True
                    break # exit the for loop
        if not card_found: # if card_found is still False (ie: if block inside for loop was not executed. ie: card was not found)
            player_2_choice = random.choice(player_2_hand) # <<<======== your old function
        #########################
        if player_2_choice not in player_2_hand:
            continue
        print("Player 2 asked for ", player_2_choice)
        if check_guess(player_1_hand, player_2_hand, player_2_choice, player_2_pairs)==Tr:
            print("Player 2 got a pat on the back for guessing correctly.")
        else:
            print("Player 2 had to go fishing!!!")
            drawn_card = player_2_hand[-1]
            if check_d_card(player_2_hand, player_2_pairs, player_2_choice, d_card)==True:
                print("Player 2 got a pat on the back for drawing their pair")
            elif check_d_card(player_2_hand, player_2_pairs, player_2_choice, d_card)==F:
                for i in range(len(player_2_hand)):
                    for j in range(i + 1, len(player_2_hand):
                        # If card ranks match
                        card1 = player_2_hand[i]
                        card2 = player_2_hand[j]
                        if card1[0] == card2[0]:
                            player_2_pairs.extend([card1, card2])
                            player_2_hand.remove(card1)
                            player_2_hand.remove(card2)
                            break
            break
```

Comment: How would I set this up so I can subtract the desired card from the list of options for my random.choice function? I am trying to set it up for the computer to remember the card I asked for so that it can ask for it if they draw the card later. Also I am trying to make it remember the ones it asks for so I can prevent them from asking for it again for a certain number of turns.

Comment: I edited my answer. try it. the `for_player_2` List will be available in other turns of game.

Comment: your right, it is available now. Now I just have to figure out how to set up an if statement that checks to see if player2 has the card from for_player_2 in their hand and if they do they will ask for that card. If not the random.choice function will pick the card that player2 wants to ask for.

Comment: see my new updated answer

Comment: we are getting close. When the check is checking for_player_2 and player_2_hand, it needs to check to see if the card is in both lists by comparing the first character of each element, and if it finds a match, player_2_choice will be set equal to the card match. Then it will print a message like this: print("Player 2 asked for, " player_2_choice)

Comment: see update where `hand_card` is set

Comment: For your information, your code is so bad. you need to comment it more and learn OOP to use classes. If you plan to maintain this project in the future, you must format it better and learn how to use classes. otherwise, you will struggle in it or you will have to rewrite the whole program after learning Object Oriented Programming